# How to add a calendar date input in forms to accept dates?

Tags: javascript, css, date, input, calendar

[I want this type of calendar to be visible and select input date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT9iy.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways.

For the selection, you can build it with a tag or button.

I don't know what languages and platform(project, server, etc) you are gonna take. However, you can calculate the number of dates with the current time. So, If you know some JavaScript, you can try with that fact.

For instance, the a tag or the button can have value like this:

```
<a id="date" href="#">30</a>
```

If you use jQuery ( from JavaScript ), you can get 30.

```
$('#date').on('click', function(){
    var date = $(this).text();
});
```

If you want to get the year and the month you can give them id in the tag and get it.

If you want to make it simple, the page shouldn't have the tags from all the dates( For example, the dates from 1990~2018... Jan to Dec... 1~31...) at the time. However, you can manipulate it with jQuery. For instance, Let's say you have one left, right button for changing the year. If you press left, just change the number of year like this:

```
var currentYear = $('#year').text();
$('#year').text(--currentYear);
```

For the format, using table can be used. However, you can also use div. And just give them different class and implement it.

Comment: It's pointless answering this kind of question, particularly with such a vague answer and dependency on a library that isn't tagged or mentioned in the OP.